# Apache HTTPD allow access for multiple users from their respective IPs

Tags: apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

Directory on the server needs to be accessed by multiple users and each user can have access only if they are accessing from specific IP with their credentials. I only find syntax how to describe this with **and** conjunction (`RequireAll`) for single user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Without having tested, something along these lines should do it (but will be painful to maintain if you have many users and they change often):

```
<RequireAny>
  <RequireAll>
  Require ip 10.0.0.1
  Require user one
  </RequireAll>

  <RequireAll>
  Require ip 10.0.0.2
  Require user two
  </RequireAll>
</RequireAny>
```

Comment: Did not think this was possible. Will try out